# React Native SMS module

Tags: react-native, sms

I want to be able to send a SMS from a react native application natively withou open the actually sms application on ios or android. Does anyone know of any was of making this happen without without using a API such as twilio or Nexmo?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this package [react-native-sms-android](https://github.com/rhaker/react-native-sms-android)
But it only works for Android.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`react-native-sms-x`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-sms-x)   package.

You just need to add this project in `setting.gradle` and `build.gradle` files. then the below code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TouchableOpacity,
  ToastAndroid
} from 'react-native';
import SendSMS from 'react-native-sms-x';

export default class RNSMS extends Component {
  sendSMSFunction() {
    SendSMS.send(123, "+95912345678", "Hey.., this is me!\nGood to see you. Have a nice day.",
      (msg)=>{
        ToastAndroid.show(msg, ToastAndroid.SHORT);
      }
    );
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>        
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={this.sendSMSFunction.bind(this)}>
          <Text>Send SMS</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },  
  button: {
    padding: 10,
    borderWidth: .5,
    borderColor: '#bbb',
    margin: 10,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center'
  }
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('RNSMS', () => RNSMS);
```

For more info refer https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-sms-x